# How to set YouTube to show all subscriptions / enable the subscription bell for all subscriptions at once?

Tags: youtube, notifications

It's no longer enough to "just subscribe" to actually see all new videos in one's YouTube feed. One has to go to its [YouTube subscription manager](https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager) and hit the bell.

I subscribe to 100+ channels. (Most are small channels, with very few videos per year.) It would be tedious to click on the bell for each subscription.

Can I somehow set "yes, just show am all the videos for all the channels I subscribed to in chronological order"?

Answer (score 2):

The only answer as of Aug2 2021 discusses if the YouTube bell has an effect or not. I feel this doesn't help the OP concretely.

I was in the same boat, wanting to ring the bell on something like 500 subscriptions so I stop missing videos. I ended up going to the [subscriptions page](https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels) and running this piece of JavaScript in the DevTools console:

```
$$('ytd-subscription-notification-toggle-button-renderer').forEach((x,i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    x.click()
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('ytd-menu-service-item-renderer').click(), 100)
  }, i * 300)
})
```

It's crude but did the job for me. It clicks on each subscription bell icon, then clicks on "show all".

- You need to first scroll down the page to preload all subscriptions
- You may want to play with the numbers to increase delay between actions, if it's too fast on your system.

Comment: this is amazing! how can i change it to select "none" rather than "all" notifications?

Comment: figured it out. use this instead. document.querySelectorAll('ytd-menu-service-item-renderer')[2].click()

Answer (score -1):

> It's no longer enough to "just subscribe" to actually see all new videos in one's YouTube feed. One has to go to its YouTube subscription manager and hit the bell.

Wrong. If you subscribe to a channel, you will see all their videos in the subscription feed. The bell is just about push/email notifications.

> Can I somehow set "yes, just show am all the videos for all the channels I subscribed to in chronological order"?

If you are on YouTube, click the three-bar-menu in the top left corner and then "Subscriptions".

Comment: "It's no longer enough to "just subscribe" to actually see all new videos in one's YouTube feed.." - It's right.

Default settings is "highlights only".

Quote https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/5ryh45/my_subscriptions_tab_should_be_telling_me_what/ddbg4vm/?st=j395l9cf&sh=381b15ac

"You can set for which channel you want to get notifications on https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager. Black bell (default) means highlights only, black bell with lines around it means all videos, outlined bell crossed through mens no notifications."

Comment: A ton of youtubers, a few of them I know personally, I noticed drops in viewers when youtube changed this. A ton of youtubers made videos about this and users complained about this.

Comment: I wrote the comment you are quoting. The context of it is that the reddit-OP didn't want videos from his subscriptions to occasionally show up in the notification bell. So no, the bell has nothing to do with the subscription feed.

Comment: As for the YouTubers who drop views: There are tons of reasons why views fluctuate. One of them is whether YouTube is recommending one of your videos on a certain other videos or not. Another whether YouTube's home page (as opposed to subscription page) is featuring more videos from the subscriptions or more from outside your usual sources. Pointing at view fluctuation to show that subscriptions doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: `Wrong. If you subscribe to a channel, you will see all their videos in the subscription feed. The bell is just about push/email notifications.` That's not true. I too have noticed that new videos that are posted by a significant number of the channels I am subscribed to do not appear in my subscription feed... this is probably also happening to you. Manually go through your subscribed channels, and I'm betting you'll find a few that have posted videos that didn't appear in your news feed. From what I've gathered, YouTube changed the subscription page to only show you the videos that

Comment: [con't] YouTube's algorithm thinks you'll want to watch, based off of what you've been watching lately. Which is dumb.

I too would like to find a way to make it so that all new videos posted by all of the channels I'm subscribed to show up on my subscriptions page.

Comment: YouTube confirmed several times that they don't intentionally use algorithms on the subscriptions feed (other than ordering them reverse chronologically). There may be a delay between the video being uploaded and it actually showing up, causing it to show up after new videos have been uploaded, and if you scroll long enough, videos by some channels eventually start to disappear, but it doesn't filter out videos based on whether they think you don't want to watch it.

Comment: If you do find another instance of a video not showing up, send feedback with the string "SubsFeedback". That'll automatically open a bug.