# How to set YouTube to disable the subscription/notification bell for all subscriptions at once?

Tags: youtube, notifications

I have more than 800 subscriptions on YouTube. Is there a way to set all subscription/notification bells to "None"? This is so I can enable the bell later for important channels.

Answer (score 2):

The comment on [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158166) on how to enable the notification bell worked for me.

Enable all notifications:

```
$$('ytd-subscription-notification-toggle-button-renderer').forEach((x,i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    x.click()
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('ytd-menu-service-item-renderer').click(), 100)
  }, i * 300)
})
```

Disable all notifications:

```
$$('ytd-subscription-notification-toggle-button-renderer').forEach((x,i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    x.click()
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelectorAll('ytd-menu-service-item-renderer')[2].click(), 100)
  }, i * 300)
})
```

[Source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106469/how-to-set-youtube-to-show-all-subscriptions-enable-the-subscription-bell-for#comment143774_158166)